# Maven cycle dependency

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I'm new to Maven and Im trying to make my own Java EE Maven project with some frameworks...
I have started with two modules and one parent module.
The problem is that Im getting this error when Im issue mvn clean:

```
[ERROR] The projects in the reactor contain a cyclic reference: Edge between 'Vertex{label='org.tepo:Jporto-web:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'}' and 'Vertex{label='org.tepo:Jporto-ejb:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'}' introduces to cycle in the graph org.tepo:Jporto-ejb:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT --> org.tepo:Jporto-web:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT --> org.tepo:Jporto-ejb:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
```

I know what cycle dependency is, but I can not see such a thing in my poms. Here They are:
parent POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.tepo</groupId>
  <artifactId>Jporto</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>jsf library tutto</name>
  <description>fiesta prego grande</description>
  <dependencies>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.tepo</groupId>
        <artifactId>Jporto-ejb</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.tepo</groupId>
        <artifactId>Jporto-web</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>war</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>

  <modules>
    <module>Jporto-ejb</module>
    <module>Jporto-web</module>
  </modules>

  <build>  
  <plugins>  
    <plugin>  
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>  
      <inherited>true</inherited>  
      <configuration>  
        <source>1.6</source>  
        <target>1.6</target>  
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>  
        <version>2.5.1</version>
      </configuration>  
    </plugin>  
    <plugin>  
      <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>  
      <configuration>  
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>  
      </configuration>  
    </plugin>  
    <plugin>  
      <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>  
      <inherited>true</inherited>  
      <configuration>  
        <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>  
      </configuration>  
    </plugin>  
  </plugins>  
</build>  

</project>
```

WEB module:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <artifactId>Jporto</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.tepo</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>Jporto-web</artifactId>
  <groupId>org.tepo</groupId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <dependencies>    
    <dependency>  
  <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>  
  <artifactId>jms</artifactId>  
  <version>1.1</version>  
  <scope>provided</scope>  
</dependency> 

<dependency>  
  <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>  
  <artifactId>jta</artifactId>  
  <version>1.1</version>  
  <scope>provided</scope>  
</dependency>  

<dependency>  
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>  
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>  
  <version>4.0.0.Final</version>  
  <scope>provided</scope>  
</dependency>  

<dependency>  
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>  
  <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>  
  <version>4.0.0.Final</version>  
  <scope>provided</scope>  
</dependency>  

<dependency>  
  <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>  
  <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>  
  <version>1.0.1.Final</version>  
  <scope>provided</scope>  
</dependency>  

<dependency>  
  <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>  
  <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec</artifactId>  
  <version>1.0.0.Final</version>  
  <scope>provided</scope>  
</dependency>  

<dependency>  
  <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>  
  <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>  
  <version>2.1</version>  
  <scope>provided</scope>  
</dependency>  



  </dependencies>
</project>
```

EJB module:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>Jporto</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.tepo</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <groupId>org.tepo</groupId>
  <artifactId>Jporto-ejb</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>ejb</packaging>

  <dependencies>  

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-as-ejb3</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.0.CR1b</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Please, can ypu explain to me why Im getting this error ?
also, eclipse gives this error on pom file of web module: Missing artifact org.tepo:Jporto-web:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
and
Missing artifact org.tepo:Jporto-ejb:ejb:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile on web module... 
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your parent pom depends on your modules which depend on your parent pom.

What you could have done is add to your parent pom

```
<modules>
   <module>module1</module>
   <module>module2</module>
</module>
```

Your modules have to be subdirectories with the names you give them.

Comment: Yeah,that's what I have in my parent POM. You can see it in first code snippet that I have posted...

Comment: Yes, but you have your projects both defined as modules and as dependencies. Just remove the dependencies and you should be fine.

Comment: okey, that did the trick!
I would swear that I have read it in some tutorial.. :/
Thank you!